# Connect a Winforms app to a SQL Server from a computer without SQL Server 2017 installed

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2017

To start, I am fairly new to both Visual Studio and SQL Server. I am attempting to run an application from computer B which does not have SQL Server installed, and have it connect to a SQL Server database that is hosted on computer A. Both computers are connected over Wi-Fi to the same network.

I have enabled remote connections in SSMS as well as started the SQL Server Browser in `services.msc`. Exceptions for 1433 and 1434 ports have been added in the Windows firewall out and in rules. In SQL Server config manager I have TCP\IP enabled and the IPAll section in properties has the TCP port set to 1433.

The problem is when I try to add a user to a login on SSMS it only looks for logins on my host machine(I don't know if this is how it should work but I digress). So I am using a SQL Server login username and password (that is enabled in SSMS) in my connection string in the Winforms app.

However, when I run the published app from computer B, I get this error:

> Login Failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with integrated authentication

How would I rectify this problem to make computer B a trusted domain?

Like I said I am new to SQL Server and VS so a lot of what I found online was either too complicated or I had already done. Thanks in advance.

Edit: My connection string is "Data Source=DESKTOP-24DR8LC\SQLEXPRESS2; Initial Catalog=HouseFinances; User ID = user; Password = password;Integrated Security = False"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I need to check a connection string I do the following:

1. Create a new text file on the desktop called test.txt.
2. I rename it test.udl.
3. Double clicking on that file will bring up the Data Link Properties window.
4. Start on the first tab and select your source, go to the second tab and fill in the properties for your connection.
5. Click the test connection button.
6. If everything connects ok, close the window and open the file using notepad.
7. In there you will find your connection string.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I received the string "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Initial Catalog=HouseFinances;Data Source=DESKTOP-24DR8LC\SQLEXPRESS2". But when I run this it says: "System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'provider'.'". After removing the provider part from the string it runs on Computer A but Computer B still gives the same error.

Comment: did you create a UDL file on computer B and run it from there to test the connection?

Comment: I did not however adding "Integrated Security = False" worked for some reason?  Very cool trick though to get the connection string. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is specifying Integrated Security or TrustedConnection.  You need to remove those options and add the User and Password for the SQL account

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ is an excellent resource for this.  [SQL Server > .Net > Standard Security](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/standard-security/) in particular.

Comment: This is my connection string: "Data Source=DESKTOP-24DR8LC\\SQLEXPRESS2; Initial Catalog=HouseFinances; User ID = user; Password = password;" Do I need to add "Integrated Security = False"?

Comment: Remove the Integrated Security parameter altogether

Comment: For some reason It worked by adding "Integrated Security = False". I don't know why though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: well, it would, it's just cleaner to leave it out, since false is the default setting